how to add custom text in woocommerce order meta details in admin order page?

<input type="color" id="product-color" name="product_color" value="#000000" class="color-picker" />
I added a custom color code input on a single product page. When ordering this custom color code seems okay on the cart page.
I want to add custom color value input text to the admin edit order page.
